I am trying open a new form inside a panel of another form. But control is not passing
[enter image description here][1]I am trying open a new form inside a panel of another form. But control is not passing. I am providing the code snippet below. The code is written in C# windows form.
I have tried every code available on YouTube and I think code is correct. But I am unable to find out why the control is not passing.
`private void btnDashboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
Panel p = this.Parent as Panel;
if(p != null)
{
    frmDashboard f = new frmDashboard();
    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    f.TopLevel= false;
    f.AutoScroll = true;
    p.Controls.Add(f);
    f.Show();
    this.Close();
}`


correctlogin correc = new correctlogin() { TopLevel = false, TopMost = true };
correc.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
guna2Panel1.Controls.Add(correc);
correc.Show();

correctlogin is the name of my form and guna2panel1 is my panel
I think this is what your trying to accomplish, if im incorrect try to elaborate more and i might be able to help. If you dont know what this does all this does is show a form i already made in a panel.
